# Working with huff contract in foundry (a few questions)

Tags: solidity, blockchain, testing, foundry, huff

I'm trying to deploy huff contract in foundry to goerli testnet (it is deployed), BUT:

1. Why is so that my runtime code looks like it was written in Solidity ? Is there a way to avoid this and create contract in foundry with Huff bytecode inside and then interact with it via cast calls?
2. I'm not able to **cast send** anything to my functions. There is no output in the terminal (no error nor success). I'm trying to send it with raw calldata:

```
cast send $CONTRACT_ADDRESS 5c989c4400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005() --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY --rpc-url $RPC_URL
```

and also with *"string"* approach:

```
cast send $CONTRACT_ADDRESS "provideValue(uint32)" 5 --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY --rpc-url $RPC_URL
```

Huff contract:

```
#define function provideValue(uint32) nonpayable returns () 
#define function getResult() view returns (uint256)

#define constant VALUE = FREE_STORAGE_POINTER() // slot 0

#define macro PROVIDE_VALUE() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    0x04 calldataload [VALUE] sstore
}

#define macro GET_RESULT() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    [VALUE] sload
    0x00 mstore
    0x20 0x00 return
}

#define macro MAIN() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    0x00 calldataload 0xe0 shr

    dup1 __FUNC_SIG(provideValue) eq provide jumpi
    dup1 __FUNC_SIG(getResult) eq result jumpi

    provide:
        PROVIDE_VALUE()
    result:
        GET_RESULT()
}
```

script/Deploy.s.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "foundry-huff/HuffDeployer.sol";
import "forge-std/Script.sol";

interface IHuff {
    function provideValue(uint32) external;

    function getResult() external returns (uint256);
}

contract Deploy is Script {
    function run() public returns (IHuff iHuff) {
        iHuff = IHuff(HuffDeployer.deploy("HuffContract"));
    }
}
```

All help is much appreciated ! Thank you.

Comment: I found an answer to all of my questions here: <br/>
https://mirror.xyz/0xF314e9Cc3D5F382669eeB01d31f421aF931b9eBB/H9-kta5z47jO-_Fg9Hv93D6xHcPCFgvfxCIQ26zI5hk <br/>
I hope it helps someone as well !

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try using HuffConfig then use that to deploy the huff contract

```
 HuffConfig config = HuffDeployer.config();
```

Then

```
iHuff = IHuff(config.deploy("HuffContract"));
```

Comment: It's not working. I've got an error: Dynamic linking not supported in `create` command - deploy the following library contracts first, then provide the address to link at compile time